# Nested ListView ItemDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net

tryin' to render articles with pictures for each article.
Im trying to use 2 nested ListView's and 2 querys in SQL Server 08 which i get in 2 methods from my 2 objectdatasources...

My ListViews look like this: http://pastebin.com/Lf1Evd1d
and my code-behinde like this: http://pastebin.com/0YebPk15

Problem is I'm not really sure how to write the ItemDataBound. Im trying to get it to render with NyhetID connected with the each picture from the database. I think its wrong at the databound point. Just get an error which says that my method is non-generic and got something wrong with an ID...

If anyone got other suggestions on how to reneder out articles with picture for each article please share :)

Regards /Haris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by your question, but the `ItemDataBound` event shouldn't work any differently for a nested control.

```
<asp:ListView ID="innerList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="innerList_ItemDataBound" ...>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
protected void innerList_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Sorry James, I'll try to rephrase my question. In my nested listview i want to render out each picture belogning to an article. On my itemdatabound i want to connect those picture ID's from my database that are connected with the article ID. Thing is i don't understand how to write the ItemDataBound to get it to work...

As i understand first ListView renders out Article, when it gets to Eval"Picture" it looks for Articles ID to find an matching Picture...or am I thinkin wrong? And hey I appreciate you're respond!!

Comment: Eval"Picture" is in my inner listview as i forgot to mention